# How are these equations derived?

Tags: pade-approximation

In the below snippet, the equations are listed that need to be used to solve for the Padé approximant. **How are these equations derived**? I get they want the derivatives to be equal at zero, but I don't see how those equations follow from that knowledge.

[image]

Comment: What is the connection between the derivatives at zero of a power series and its coefficients?

Comment: How does that help? $R(x)$ is not a power series, it's a fraction of power series, so to get derivatives, I need quotient rule.

Comment: Could you provide the source of the snippet? Pade approximation is defined by (3). It is not that obvious to me that it is should be equivalent to (5). BTW, `b_0` can be set to 1 without loss of generality.